# How To Access Flutter Run Web Server From My Phone

Tags: flutter, dart, localhost

I can create a localhost  trough this command:

```
flutter run --release -d web-server --web-hostname=0.0.0.0 --web-port=3000
```

But it's only available on my laptop,

How can i get that output in my other devices connected to that same network..

Comment: What's your laptop's DNS name? That's what you need to connect. The DNS server in your network or router maps machine names to IPs. In a home network, the DNS service is provided by the router and the machine name is the machine's name. The IP *can* change, especially in a home network, but the DNS server will always map the same machine name to the IP

Comment: On Linux you can use `hostname` to get the machine's name. In both Windows and Linux you can use `nslookup` to find the IP for a name and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use utilities such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that will help you access your 'localhost' from the internet.